# Parsing XML with UTF-8 in c++

Tags: c++, xml, utf-8

I am having some trouble reading XML-documents.
I have tried both TinyXML and TinyXML2 but i am struggling with the Scandinavian characters [Æ,Ø,Å,æ,ø,å].
I have pasted code for both TinyXML and TinyXML2
Can anyone see what is wrong with my code?
Or maybe some of you have a suggestion for another XML parser?

TinyXML

```
string verdi;
XMLDocument doc;
doc.LoadFile("C:/OneDriveSync/OneDrive - Asplan Viak/Desktop/Testfiler/EksempelData_LedningsnettEtablertEllerFlyttet_v20190101.gml");
XMLElement* root = doc.RootElement();
for (XMLNode* e = root->FirstChildElement(); e != NULL; e = e->NextSiblingElement())
{
    verdi = e->Value();
    if (verdi.find("app:vertikalnivå") < verdi.length())
    {
        log.Skriv("Funnet");
    }
    log.Skriv(verdi);
    for (XMLNode* v = e->FirstChildElement(); v != NULL; v = v->NextSiblingElement())
    {
        verdi = v->Value();
        if (verdi.find("app:vertikalnivå") < verdi.length())
        {
            log.Skriv("Funnet");
        }
        log.Skriv(verdi);
        for (XMLNode* k = v->FirstChildElement(); k != NULL; k = k->NextSiblingElement())
        {
            verdi = k->Value();
            if (verdi.find("app:vertikalnivå") < verdi.length())
            {
                log.Skriv("Funnet");
            }
            log.Skriv(verdi);
        }
    }
}
```

TinyXML2

```
string verdi;
TiXmlDocument doc2("C:/OneDriveSync/OneDrive - Asplan Viak/Desktop/Testfiler/EksempelData_LedningsnettEtablertEllerFlyttet_v20190101.gml");
TiXmlEncoding encoding = TIXML_ENCODING_UTF8;
doc2.LoadFile(encoding);
TiXmlElement* l_pRootElement = doc2.RootElement();

if (l_pRootElement != NULL)
{
    for (TiXmlNode* e = l_pRootElement->FirstChildElement(); e != NULL; e = e->NextSiblingElement())
    {
        verdi = e->Value();
        if (verdi.find("app:vertikalnivå") < verdi.length())
        {
            log.Skriv("Funnet");
        }
        log.Skriv(verdi);
        for (TiXmlNode* v = e->FirstChildElement(); v != NULL; v = v->NextSiblingElement())
        {
            verdi = v->Value();
            if (verdi.find("app:vertikalnivå") < verdi.length())
            {
                log.Skriv("Funnet");
            }
            log.Skriv(verdi);
            for (TiXmlNode* k = v->FirstChildElement(); k != NULL; k = k->NextSiblingElement())
            {
                verdi = k->Value();
                if (verdi.find("app:vertikalnivå") < verdi.length())
                {
                    log.Skriv("Funnet");
                }
                log.Skriv(verdi);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is (probably) that your code is not UTF-8, not a problem with the libraries. For instance what makes you think that `"app:vertikalnivå"` is a UTF-8 string?

Comment: Try the following, replace `"app:vertikalnivå"` with `"app:vertikalniv\xc3\xa5"` That definitely is a UTF-8 string

Comment: If you use MSVC, you need the `/utf-8` flag

Comment: Thank you, all the comments were very helpful.

Comment: Or, if your compiler supports C++11 or later, use the `u8` prefix to tell the compiler you want a string literal to be UTF-8 encoded, eg: `u8"app:vertikalnivå"`.